# Can you combine elemental gold and boron?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, elements

Is it possible to combine gold and boron to form compounds? A simple example being:

$$
\ce{Au + B -> AuB}
$$

Comment: yes. http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-45280-5_27

Comment: @MaxW Thank ! is my equation correct  or am i missing something ? Also is the reaction made with gaseous gold and bore ?

Comment: That is the overall reaction but making AuB isn't as easy as the equation would make it seem. Gold is a solid at room temperature of course.

Comment: @MaxW yeah of course, but heating the reactants at 2075° (so the bore and gold should be liquid) (bore fusion point is 2075 and gold is 1064)  and then freezing down the solution would work ?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. No point in me speculating and telling you wrong. But at a temperature of 2000 degrees how do you protect the material from atmospheric oxygen? What container material do you use? And so on...

Comment: AuB does exist, at least in gas phase.

Comment: http://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1675226

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, gold and boron can bond with each other to form alloy clusters. They are very important in semiconductor industry and used in fabrication process. Here(1) is a short note on gold-boron alloy:

> **Photoelectron spectroscopy and density-functional theory are combined to investigate the electronic and structural properties of a
>   series of $\ce{B-Au}$ alloy clusters: $\ce{B6Au_{n}^{−}}$ and
>   $\ce{B6Au_{n}}$ ($\ce{n = 1−3}$).** Rich spectral features are
>   observed for each species, and vibrational structures are resolved for
>   numerous detachment transitions of $\ce{B6Au^−}$ and
>   $\ce{B6Au^{2−}}$. Electron affinities of $\ce{B6Au_{n} (n = 1−3)}$ are
>   evaluated to be 2.70 ± 0.03, 2.91 ± 0.02, and 3.21 ± 0.05 eV,
>   respectively. Global structural searches are performed for both the
>   anions and their neutrals. The calculated electronic binding energies
>   are compared with experimental measurements to establish the anion
>   global-minimum structures and their corresponding neutral states.
>   The ground-state structures of these clusters are shown to be planar
>   or quasi-planar with an elongated B6core, to which the first and
>   second Au atoms are bonded terminally and the third Au in a bridging
>   position. All three anion clusters are π antiaromatic.
>   Natural bond orbital analyses show that the $\ce{B-Au}$ bonding is
>   highly covalent, providing new examples for the $\ce{Au/H}$ analogy
>   in Au alloy clusters.

You can find more information about gold-boron alloy clusters in the reference below.

**Reference**

1. The Journal of Chemical Physics 138, 084306 (2016); doi: http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4792501
2. https://www.google.com/patents/US3211550
3. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23901981
4. http://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4816010
5. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235886590_On_the_structures_and_bonding_in_boron-gold_alloy_clusters_B6Aun-_and_B6Aun_n_1-3
6. http://www.google.co.in/patents/US3137595

Answer (score 4):

In a rather different vein is boronizing gold for surface hardening.  Here boron combines not with the gold but with a base metal alloyed into the gold.  According to the abstract from*  (full article behind  a paywall):

> Surface hardening of gold containing Ti, Zr, Hf, V, Nb, Ta, Cr, Mn,
>   Fe, Co or Ni was tried by means of boronizing technique with powder
>   boron under argon atmospheric furnace at 900 to 950 degree C for 6
>   hrs. The obvious surface hardening was possible for the gold alloy
>   which contains more than 5%Ti, 5%V, 3%Cr, 15%Mn, 10%Fe, 5%Co or 5%Ni.
>   Surface hardness and thickness of the hardened layer strongly depended
>   on the alloying element added. The phases formed on the hardened
>   surface were investigated by X-ray diffraction analysis.

**Reference**

*https://www.researchgate.net/publication/29677483_Surface_Hardening_of_Gold_with_Boronizing_TechniqueMaterials_Metallurgy_Weldability